# java avoid Objects pass by reference

Tags: java, oop

I'm facing problem with object cloning in java.

```
public class TestClass {

private int count;
private List<Integer> list;
public final int getCount() {
    return count;
}
public final void setCount(int count) {
    this.count = count;
}
public final List<Integer> getList() {
    return list;
}
public final void setList(List<Integer> list) {
    this.list = list;
}

}


public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
TestClass obj = new TestClass();
obj.setCount(5);
List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
temp.add(1);
temp.add(2);
obj.setList(temp);

TestClass newObj= obj;


System.out.println(newObj.getList().size());
obj.getList().add(3);
System.out.println(newObj.getList().size());


}

}
```

The output I'm getting here is 2,3. But my desired output is 2,2 but since java assign reference of "obj" to newObj. Is there anyway to avoid this? I have seen that serialize the object and deserialize it will give brand new reference to "newObj". But is there anyother efficient ways?

Comment: you have only one TestClass instance. you can create a clone of obj, and you can get then different sizes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you aren't actually *cloning* which in java means you use the `object.clone()` method.  clone makes a *shallow* copy of an object.  You just made a 2nd reference to the same object.

In your code, calling

```
obj.getList().add(3);
```

Is the same as

```
newObj.getList().add(3);
```

Which is why it is printing the way it is.

You need to make a **deep** copy of the object so not only is the instance of `TestClass` different, but all the fields are different too.

The easiest way to do this is to make a copy method and/or a copy constructor

```
public class TestClass{
      public TestClass(){
      }

      //copy constructor
      public TestClass( TestClass copy){
         this.list = new ArrayList<Integer>(copy.list);
         this.count = copy.count;
      }

      ...
 }
```

Then to use it :

```
TestClass newObj= new TestClass(obj);
```

Comment: One more point. the `clone()` method in java doesn't do a **deep copy**. That is why you need to make a **deep copy** your self (as this answer says..)

Comment: @TheLostMind thanks, I added the actual deep copy code and explicitly mentioned `clone()` makes a shallow copy